# control reaches end of non-void function(c++)

Tags: c++, function

I have this modefied binary search function that finds the lowest( the value that is closest to L - a known value) and the highest value in a vector(the value that is closest to R - the same known value). Unfortunatelty, when I try to compile the code I get this warning and I dont know why: control reaches end of non-void function.

```
int bs_counts (vector <int> Arr, int x, int low, int high, bool searchDirection)
 {
     bool done = false;
     int new_middle = 0;
      int mid = (low + high)/2;
     
     while(low <= high && done == true)
     {
         if(Arr[mid] == x)
         {
             new_middle = mid;
             done = true;
         }
         else if(Arr[mid] > x)
         {
             high = mid - 1;
         }
         else
         {
             low = mid + 1;
         }
     }
        if(done == true)
        {
            return new_middle;
        }
        else
        {
            if(searchDirection == true)
            {
                return low;
            }
            else if (searchDirection == false)
            {
                return high;
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: Ask yourself: What happens in your function if `low` is greater than `high` when you enter the function

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you please explain it a little bit more?

Comment: The warning is a false positive; you're returning from all paths in the function. However, you have undefined behavior if `low` is greater than `high` since indexing with `mid` is probably invalid. Please format your code; the indentation of the `if` condition is highly misleading.

Comment: That `while` loop will never run. `done` is initialized to `false`, and the loop only runs when `done` is `true`. And note that `done == true` is redundant; just use `done` when you need to test it.

Answer (score 2):

1st of all, please format your code properly, as it looks like the 3 `return` statements are inside the `while` loop, which isn't the case.

The compiler is confused, look at this fragment of code.

```cpp
if (done == true)
{
    return new_middle;
}
else
{
    if (searchDirection == true)
    {
        return low;
    }
    else if (searchDirection == false)
    {
        return high;
    }
}
```

We can obviously see that `searchDirection` will be either `true` or `false`, and something will always be returned, but the compiler might be overlooking that, change it to the following.

```cpp
if (done == true)
{
    return new_middle;
}
else
{
    if (searchDirection == true)
    {
        return low;
    }
    else
    {
        return high;
    }
}
```

And the warning disappeared.

Comment: Could even simplify `if (searchDirection == true)` to `if (searchDirection)`. Or, `return searchDirection ? low : high;`.